# Edge not running javascript properly after changing file

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web, microsoft-edge

I have a pretty general problem with Edge that is not present on other browsers.
I am working on a project, and want to change one function inside a .js file.

Step 1 - Open Edge, run the function via button - it works.

Step 2 - Change the function slightly, for example add one console.log("hi"), then save it.

Step 3 - Clear cache, ctrl+F5, button now does nothing, does not even throw an error in the console

Step 4 - Revert the modifications on the .js file (delete the line of code).

Step 5 - Clear cache, ctrl+F5, button still does nothing, does not even throw an error in the console.

Each of these steps works properly in both Chrome and FF.
This seems like a security setting that does not allow changes on the file, but i couldn't find anything useful online.

Any ideas on how to make it work on edge?